PageRank in directed graphs: equivalence of iterative and eigenvalue methods
Given a directed graph $ G $ with $ n $ nodes, we can represent this graph using an adjacency matrix $ A $. The stochastic matrix $ S $ can be derived from the adjacency matrix using the following formula:
$$
S[i][j] = \frac{A[i][j]}{C(j)}
$$
where $ C(j) $ is the number of outbound links from node $ j $.
We start with an initial PageRank vector, which is typically uniform across all nodes:
$$
PR_0 = \left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}\right]
$$
To compute the PageRank values, we employ an iterative process. We repeat this process until the values converge. The PageRank vector can be expressed using the following formula:
$$
PR = (1 - d) \cdot \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} +  S^T PR
$$
In this formula:

$1$ is a vector of ones,
$ d$ is the damping factor, commonly set to $ 0.85$.

This equation balances the uniform distribution of the initial PageRank values with the contributions from the neighboring nodes, reflecting the probabilistic nature of a user's navigation through the directed graph.
Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues, and let $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ be the eigenvalue with the maximum absolute value among all eigenvalues. Let $v_{\text{max}}$ be the corresponding eigenvector of $\lambda_{\text{max}}$. One can verify that $v_{\text{max}}$ also determines the PageRanks of the nodes.

Q It seems that these two methods should coincide. If so, is there a proof of this equivalence?

p.s. I tested both approaches on a sample of 8,000 diagonalizable matrices, each with a distinct set of eigenvalues. Using the Kendall tau metric to compare their alignment revealed a maximum correlation of only 35%. This indicates that the two methods can be considered entirely different for ranking nodes in a directed graph whose adjacency matrix is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues. However, in this case, eigenvector centrality appears to be a much more reliable method for ranking the nodes.
So, we are faced with the question: why is the PageRank algorithm, which is commonly used, considered reliable?

(i) "an iterative process" ... What process, exactly? (ii) "can be expressed using the following formula" ... Is this supposed to mean "satisfies the following equation"? (iii) "the corresponding eigenvector of $\lambda_{\text{max}}$" ... There are infinitely many eigenvectors for each eigenvalue. So, what is the "the" here supposed to mean? (iv) "It seems that these two methods should coincide" ... What two methods? (v) "One can verify that $v_{\text{max}}$ also determines the PageRanks of the nodes." ... Determines how?

@Iosif Pinelis,  Many thanks for your attention in details. (i)  the iterative process is this one, $
PR = (1 - d) \cdot \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1} +  S^T PR
$. We start with an initial situation, as given, and it keep going up to a convergence.  (ii) No, by this formula the final result will be obtained. (iii) Since diagonalizability is assumed, the corresponded eigenspace is one dimensional.   (iv and v)  By the latter formula any node possesses a pagerank value. The eigenvector $v_{max$} also corresponds another pagerank value to each node.

w.r.t quesions (i) en (ii) of Iosif above: I think that, given that you already wrote $PR_0$ for the initial condition, it would make sense to replace the $PR$ in the LHS of the formula with $PR_{i+1}$ and the $PR$ in the RH with $PR_i$ for clarity. The question then asks for the relationship between $\lim_{i \to \infty} PR_i$ and the eigenvectors

Yes, it is exactly right.

The dominant vector for a matrix with positive entries is the unique eigenvector where all entries are positive. If anything, the PageRank algorithm is overly simplistic and too well-understood since PageRank just gives pages a positive real value of their importance instead of assigning each page a vector where the magnitude signifies importance but where the direction signifies the type of content.
